# Create action links with different routes?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

```
public class PostController : YourDefinitionController
{
    public ActionResult Test(int id ,int title)
    {
        return View();
    }
}

@Html.ActionLink("Postss", "Test","Post" ,new { title = "asdf",id=3 },null)//in Razor view

// here is route registration
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Post",
        "{Post}/{Test}/{title}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Post", action = "Test",id=UrlParameter.Optional, title=UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Defaultx", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

I expected to see link like /Post/Test/asdf/3 but it is /Post/Test/3?title=3
Why ? How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest cleaning your code a bit, because there are many things done based on conventions. So keeping code consistent often helps.

```
public ActionResult Test(string title ,int id) // Order is switched and title changed to string
```

Edit: The problem is with wrong route path. You have to change it to `"Post/Test/{title}/{id}"`

```
// changed route path expression
routes.MapRoute(
    "Post",
    "Post/Test/{title}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Post", action = "Test", title = UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Btw: If you are going to play with routes a bit more, [Phil Haack's blog](http://haacked.com/tags/Routing/default.aspx) will be a great resource.

Comment: Ah.. you got your route path wrong.. change it to `"Post/Test/{title}/{id}", `

Comment: @Freshblood: No problem ;) If your problem is solved, please mark answer as accepted for future users with similar problem.

Comment: I didn't accepted answer intentionaly and now answer is updated to right answer so i accept it.